# Cant seem to find reason for infinite loop

Tags: c++, sorting, loops, infinite-loop

Im writing a program that will help sort out classes for a 4 year college. for some reason, im getting stuck in the while loop.

```
/*
some info:
"course" is a class i created
   some of the member function are:
      bool fall()           // does the class run in the fall?
      bool spring()         // does the class run in the spring?
      string name()         // name of this course
      ...                   // plenty of irrelevant stuff


"classes" is a vector of courses
"vector <vector <course> > out" has n (generally 8) elements

"vector <string> taken" records the names of the courses that have been taken

bool prereq_taken(course C, vector <string> & taken) checks if all the 
prerequisites of the course are taken

even semesters are fall and odd are spring

*/


int x = 0, semester = 0;
while ((classes.size() > 0)){
    x %= classes.size();

if (prereq_taken(classes[x], taken)){                                            // checks if all of the prerequisites in the course have already been taken

    // my test condition
    //if ((semester % 2 == 0) && classes[x].fall() && (!classes[x].spring())){

    // Ben's condtion
    if ((semester & 1)? classes[x].spring(): classes[x].fall()){

    // my retardedly long all-in-one condition
    /*if (
        (((!(semester % 2)) && classes[x].fall() && (!classes[x].spring()))    // if fall and is only fall class or
        || ((semester % 2) && (!classes[x].fall()) && classes[x].spring())     // if spring and is only spring class
        || (classes[x].fall() && classes[x].spring())                          // if any semester class

        )                                                                      // and there is class space and enough credit space
        && (((out[semester].size() + 1) < classes_per_semester) && ((credits[semester] + classes[x].credits()) < credits_per_semester))) {
    */
        taken.push_back(classes[x].name());                                      // put class name into vector of takens
        out[semester].push_back(classes[x]);                                     // put class into final output
        classes.erase(classes.begin() + x);                                      // remove from class list
    }
    else
        x++;

 }
    else
        x++;                                                                         // else go to next class

    if ((out[semester].size() + 1) > classes_per_semester)
        semester++;
}
```

i am trying to run through all the data (and loop around) until all of the courses has been properly placed

for some reason, when i add in the if statement with the stars around it, the loop continues forever. however, without it and the `else` stuff (but with the inside stuff still in the code), the code will finish. why? is c++ boolean math somewhat different from python's (that matters to this code)?

if im vague in any way, please tell me what to clarify

Comment: Try writing formal loop invariants.  Then step through the code and see if an invariant gets broken.  Or write a couple lines of code to test the invariant.

Comment: The first if inside the while is unnecessary, because the while is taking only values when classes.size() > 0, so the clasess.size() inside that while loop will always be different from 0. Maybe you need some sleep and then take a look at this code again, because you have got some other inconsistencies corrected in the comments. Regards.

Comment: Also, what happen if you type !(classes[x].spring()) instead of (!classes[x].spring()) in the if that is giving the problem?

Comment: @Emmanuel: Moving the `!` outside the parentheses won't change anything, precedence rules cause it to be done in that order already.

Comment: @Emmanuel:no particular difference, but then again, i have no idea what is wrong, so anything can be correct, for all i care

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you think this does?

```
if ((x == classes.size()))
    x %= classes.size();
```

The assignment is the same as:

```
   x = x % classes.size();
```

But you just found out `x == classes.size()` so

```
   x = classes.size() % classes.size();
```

And for any `N`, `N%N` is zero, so that means

```
if ((x == classes.size()))
    x = 0;
```

Is that what you want?

---

The `if` in question is only capable of dealing with classes offered only in the fall.  Perhaps you wanted:

```
if ((semester & 1)? classes[x].spring(): classes[x].fall()) { ... }
```

---

Maybe this would work?

```
int x = 0, semester = 0, scheduled = 0;
vector<string> completed;
while ((classes.size() > 0)) {
    if (classes.size() == x) {
        x = 0;
        cout << "Checked all classes and scheduled " << scheduled << endl;
        if (0 == scheduled) {
            ++semester;
            completed = taken;
        }
        scheduled = 0;
    }

    if (prereq_taken(classes[x], completed)) {
        if ((semester & 1)? classes[x].spring(): classes[x].fall()) {
            if (credits[semester] + classes[x].credits() <= credits_per_semester) {
                taken.push_back(classes[x].name());
                out[semester].push_back(classes[x]);
                credits[semester] += classes[x].credits();
                cout << classes[x].name() << " will be taken in semester " << semester << " for " << classes[x].credits() << " credits" << endl;
                classes.erase(classes.begin() + x);
                scheduled++;
            }
            else {
               cout << classes[x].name() << " can't be taken in semester " << semester << " : overload on credits" << endl;
               x++;
            }
        }
        else {
            cout << classes[x].name() << " can't be taken in semester " << semester << " : not offered" << endl;
            x++;
        }    
     }
     else {
        cout << classes[x].name() << " can't be taken in semester " << semester << " : not offered" << endl;
        x++;                                                                         // 
     }

     if (out[semester].size() >= classes_per_semester || credits[semester] >= credits_per_semester) {
        cout << "Full load reached for semester " << semester << endl;
        semester++;
        completed = taken;
     }
}
```

Comment: im going to increase the if statement to include spring classes as well. im just trying to figure a part of it out first. now... to figure out what that code says... Also, its still looping. however, now its not even passing the condition

Comment: @calccrypto: If you have some spring-only classes, and no logic for deciding when to take them, you would have an infinite loop.  You'll end up with the `classes` vector having some spring-only courses and maybe some classes with a spring-only course prereq.

Comment: LOL how did i forget that??? however its still not working even through ive `cout`ed the data from within the loop

Comment: @calccrypto: I think your "fix" to the first bug is wrong.  Actually it looks like `x = 0;` wouldn't be a bad thing in that condition.

Comment: @calccrypto: Mind you, I'm pretty sure I could devise a course catalog that would break your algorithm (it's a greedy algorithm, not necessarily optimal).  Not that any real university would do such a thing, after all, it only forces students to pay tuition for extra semesters.

Comment: :) im just writing it for myself.

Comment: Ok, just always doing `x %= classes.size();` should work too.

Comment: @calccrypto: I wrote a version with helpful output showing what's going on and also tests if a semester didn't reach full load but no courses are available (e.g. wrong term or need prereqs).

Comment: yes/almost. just one thing. i still need to add the condition `(credits[semester] + classes[x].credits()) <= credits_per_semester)` so that each semester has limited number of credits as well as courses. i tried adding it in the lower if statements and its not working. im getting semesters with 37 credits/10 classes

Comment: @calccrypto: Ok, that shouldn't be too hard to handle.  I'm going to use a separate if/else so I can print a message.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you're never able to fulfill the requirements for all courses. The starred code

```
if ((semester % 2 == 0) && classes[x].fall() && (!classes[x].spring())){
```

only allows you to take fall courses. If a required course is only available in spring, your code will attempt to assign courses over an over not being able to add new courses due to missing requirements.

Now, lets assume you fix that `if` and allow the course requirements to be fulfilled. You would still depend on the data being correct (i.e. no cyclic course dependencies). I suggest reading up on [topological sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting), in case you're not familiar with it already. A simple (albeit inefficient) way to deal with the possibility of infinite loops is using the observation that at each step through the entire course list, there should have been at least one course removed from the list. So you could write something like:

```
int x = 0, semester = 0, prev_size = classes.size();
while ((classes.size() > 0)){
    if (x == classes.size()){
        x = 0;
        if( classes.size() == prev_size ) { // no courses removed in the last cycle
            // signal error
            break;
        }
        else
            prev_size = classes.size();
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An `&` by itself is a bitwise and.  You want a `&&`.  That part inside the if statement is probably never being reached, so size doesn't change.

Comment: I don't think he does want `&&`. `semester && 1`?

Comment: dont i want it to be bitwise? im trying to see if `int semester` is even or odd

Comment: @calccrypto: The correct way to check for even of oddness is: `i % 2 == 0 /* even */`. Bitwise hacks don't carry the definition of even or odd with them, and technically aren't guaranteed to always work.

Comment: Use modulus for that `semester % 2 == 0`.  The & 1 bit is unclear to the reader.

Comment: @calccrypto: The compiler will turn `semester & 1` and `semester % 2` into the exact same instruction.

Comment: @jonsca: Depends on the reader, it was perfectly clear to me.  Sometimes not understanding is the fault of the reader rather than the code.

Comment: @Ben, but doesn't the bitwise work for the negative numbers too ?

Comment: @Ben Maybe you've read enough code with that in it, but if you asked 50 people to read it quickly and discern what it was doing, you'd have a bunch of people shrugging.  It's a hack that deserves to go extinct.

Comment: @jonsca: 50 people from what population?  50 random people off the street won't have a clue what `i % 2` means.  50 people who took the same computer engineering classes I did are more likely to know what bitwise-and does than modulo.  ( a few semesters staring at AND- and OR-gates will do that :) )

Comment: @Muggen: Both positive and negative even inputs will turn into zero with both methods.